# why does create-react-app still include babel in 2020

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, babeljs, create-react-app

I understand why create-react-app included babel in 2015. But now that all 4 major browsers are quite good with ES2015(aka ES6) and even ES7, why does create-react-app need to include babel (which has a lot of dependencies and slows down the generation of a new react app quite a bit) ?

What am I missing ?

**Edit1**
I understand that they might be adding newer(ES7/ES8/ES9) features to create-react-app but isn't there a time they should stop adding Babel ?

Why isn't there a flag in my create-react-app -- which says, I don't want a babel dependency ? why isn't that a common ask of create-react-app users ?

Thank you

Comment: Probably because there are still a non-negligible number of users on legacy browsers?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues

Comment: Because, it's a continuous process. The browsers are good at ES6. But, newer features are being added all the time and they are not supported in most browsers. How many browsers support [private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields) or [String.prototype.matchAll](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-matchall)?

Comment: @adiga : Thanks. I get a perspective.

Comment: You can go through [this compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/) to see the upcoming proposals and their status. You can change the ES versions on the top menu to 6, 2016+ or Next to see the changes version wise.

Comment: Also in the case of React it will never make sense to remove a transpiling pipeline: [react preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react)

Comment: a usually react app, i guess not. maybe with next.js. i know that nuxt.js has this modern mode property witch i use https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-modern/ . It checks the browser version and returns you either the legacy code or the newer one.

Answer (score -1):

You can target the browser list as per your end users

by changing the in `package.json`

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
}
```

[docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/)

Comment: "@Kalhan Toress". Does that mean, there won't be any babel.js in my list of packages ? Why isn't there a flag in my create-react-app -- which says, I don't want a babel dependency ? why isn't that a common ask of create-react-app ?

Comment: babel is a transpiler.  It doesn't add any overhead to your code if it doesn't need to do anything to your code.  Which is virtually almost impossible, because new helpful features in JS are introduced so quickly.  It's the same reason why Chrome auto updating is so important for the web.

Comment: @user120242 while it doesn't add any overhead, it doesn't support some features of typescript and these problems are usually undocumented. Why add extra complexity to the project if it is not helpful? Even it didn't have any problems I don't see why it should be forced on developers.